# Why does Java prefer to call double constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class test {
    test(double[] a)
    {
        System.out.println("in double");
    }
    test(Object a)
    {
        System.out.println("in object");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new test(null);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I pass `null` as the constructor argument. As `null` can be anything, the above code compiles fine. When I run the code I expected it to print *in object* but it prints *in double* 
What is the reason behind this?

**NOTE** the linked question may not be duplicate because this question is related with primitive datatype vs Object

Comment: It seems like it is using the `double` because it is the first defined constructor. Have you tried defining the constructor with the `Object` parameter first?

Comment: @KErlandsson sorry I dont think its a duplicate of the linked question

Comment: @rocking a double[] is not a a primitive. Arrays are objects. `double[] instanceof Object == true`.

Comment: @KErlandsson yes true as per the link given by rgettman. my question also fits doube vs object but i can not change as accepted answer is as per double[] vs object

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason is that Java interprets `null` as any type, and when choosing the method to invoke, it will choose the most specific method that first the argument types.  Because `null` can be of the type `double[]` and a `double[]` is an `Object`, the compiler will choose the method that takes a `double[]`.  If the choices involved equally possible yet unrelated types, e.g. `double[]` and `String`, then the compiler would not be able to choose a method, and that would result in an ambiguous method call error.

The [JLS, Section 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1), states:

> The null reference can always be assigned or cast to any reference type (§5.2, §5.3, §5.5).
>
> In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type.

Comment: If I create another constructor which accepts double[] and Number then it does not compile.whats the reason?Do I have to modify my question?

Comment: @rocking The reason is that neither `double[]` nor `Number` are more specific than each other.  `double[]` isn't a subclass of `Number`, and `Number` isn't a subclass of `double[]`.  There is no "most specific method", even though both methods are applicable.  That is where the ambiguity arises; the compiler doesn't know which one to choose, so it generates an error instead.

Comment: double[] is also not related to object i mean its not subclass of object because double is primitive type. so as per your answer is there was `Double` vs `Object' then it will choose for most specific types,isnt?

Comment: @rocking Actually, [`double[]` is related to `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3).

Comment: Every class in java is a sub class to Object class.

Comment: @rocking it's not a `double`, though, it's an array of `double`, and arrays are objects (or, more precisely, `Object`s).

Answer (score 9):

Both constructors are applicable, because `null` is convertible to both `Object` and `double[]` - so the compiler needs to use overload resolution to determine which constructor to call.

[JLS 15.9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3) uses [JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) to determine the "most specific" constructor signature to use, based on which constructor has the most specific parameter types, according to [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). The exact details are slightly obscure (IMO) but in this case the basic rule of thumb of "if you can convert from T1 to T2, but not T2 to T1, then T1 is more specific" is good enough.

`double[]` is a more specific type than `Object`, because there's an implicit conversion from `double[]` to `Object`, but not vice versa.

Comment: can you tell me how to determine which is most specific type?

Comment: @rocking: I've given you a rule of thumb and specification links... I'm not sure what else you would want.

Comment: @AnilReddy: Yes, it does.

Comment: I am confused,in case of Long vs int, why long constructor is called. As per your thum rule int constructor should be called because long can converted to int but not vice versa

Comment: @rocking: that's more complicated due to the primitive vs wrapper part. If you had int and long, it would call the int overload.

Comment: int vs long does not compile but int vs Long compiles but constructor calling is done from Long ,shall I post a diiferent question for this or you can answer here?

Comment: @rocking: Are you passing null as the argument still? If so, that wouldn't work when you've got primitive parameters, quite aside from overloading.

Comment: @rocking: Okay, that wasn't at all clear - I assumed you were making a call which would at least be *valid* for both constructors. If you call `new Ideone(1)` then it calls the `int` overload.

Comment: @JonSkeet As we are discussing about null so I passed null. if we pass 1 in int vs long then it will call int because by default 1 is of int(hope i am right because in case byte vs int if you pass 1 then also int is called)

Comment: @rocking: Well, I thought you were talking about constructor overloading, with `null` just being one example. If you're unclear as to why the `int` overload wasn't chosen in that case, you should look up primitives and reference types. But `int` is implicitly convertible to `long` (and thus can be boxed to `Long`). If you had a value of type `byte` but overloads of `int` and `long`, it would still convert to `int` instead of `long`, as `int` is more specific than `long`.